# Django log operations between two publish actions

Tags: python, mysql, django

I got a problem for Django.

I have a site that has a 'publish' function.

I need to keep all changes between two 'publish' actions.

Details for example:

when first click publish, two objects(assume obj1 and obj2) stay in state state1.

Now do any change, e.g. change field of ojb1 and delete ojb2, but don't press publish.

So, currently, users from browser still see obj1 and obj2 in state state1.

Then, trigger "publish", now user should see changed obj1 and obj2 disappears.

So, firstly, I thought to use two databases(currently I use MySQL), assume db1 and db2, all views functions get data from db1 and show to users.

db2 is used to keep realtime data containning changes from administrator. 
So, when press publish button, dump db2 to db1.

This method has a problem that could produce hign latency when sync db and 
somethings really waists io resources,e.g. actually changed only two 
objects, but sync whole db.

Anyone has better idea?

Thanks.
Wesley

Comment: That's the spirit! As for the present question having two databases in this manner seems like a lot of hard work. With database vertical scaling is always easier. Get the biggest box you can afford. And if the business grows get a bigger box. then you can look at horizontal scaling.

Comment: Are you sure it's related to scaling? I thought it currently only at the functionality level.

Comment: Sorry didn't read properly. It seems to me that you don't need two databases at all. Seems like what you need is an 'archive' table + a published flag on your current table. When ever a change is made put a copy of the existing record in the archive table. The archive table can be exactly the same as your default table but with an extra archived_at column.

Comment: Hmm, currently I have multiple tables and some relationship among them, so, I wanna one way for general situation. And, currently I wanna use django database routing to setup master/slave, that, insert/update/delete operations to master, read operation to slave, but still get a problem that I don't know exactly the mechanism django routing replication between master/slave, I need to control the time when master push data to slave.

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't related to master slave replication at all. and you can't control replication on a per object basis

Comment: Umm, I will have a try these days and comments here later on